# Ejecutar primero jQuery y luego JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una duda del porque o como hacer para que primero se ejecute mi método jQuery y luego ejecute el if que tengo definido al último pero me está sucediendo todo lo contrario primero lee el if y luego el jQuery.

Primero he colocado mi jQuery que es lo que deseo ejecutar primero y luego me lea el if pero me funciona al revés.

Pdst: Soy un poco nuevo utilizando estas funcionalidades. Gracias...

```
<script>
function rS_ValidacionVentas() {
           $('#divDatosVentas').jqxValidator('validate');

            console.log(Validacion_OK_KO);

            if (Validacion_OK_KO == "OK") {
                console.log('OK');
            }
            else {
                console.log('KO');
            }
}
    </script>
```

Comment: probaste utilizando dentro del ready

Comment: Negativo tampoco funciona colega

Comment: Pon el código **html** donde estas llamando el **JQuery**

Comment: probablemente `.jqxValidator` sea asíncrono

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar los eventos que se ejecutan cuando la validación es exitosa o no.

Tu código debería quedar algo así:

```
<script>
  function rS_ValidacionVentas() {

    $('#divDatosVentas').on('validationError', function (event) { 
      console.log('Error de validación.');
    });

    $('#jqxValidator').on('validationSuccess', function (event) { 
      console.log('La validación fue exitosa.')
    }); 

    $('#divDatosVentas').jqxValidator('validate');
  }
</script>
```

Para más información, puedes revisar la documentación oficial: https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxvalidator/jquery-validator-api.htm